# Get Input Result with int 0x16

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, osdev, bios

I did this simple input function that finished when the user press the enter key:

```
input:
    mov ah, 0x00
    int 0x16
    cmp al, 0x0d
    je enter_press
    jne enter_not_press

enter_press:
    ret

enter_not_press:
    jmp input
```

How I can get the input result and put it into a variable?

Comment: Allocate space, set up a pointer to it, store `al` into there, increment pointer for next char.

Comment: This isn't 64-bit code.  `int 0x16` is 16-bit real-mode stuff.

Comment: @PeterCordes I Just started to code in assembly and i'm not expert. Sorry for the error

Comment: @Jester can you do an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Your 'simple' input function is already too convoluted! There's no real need to use all of those labels and branches. Next is the better, functionally-equivalent code:

```
WaitForEnter:
    mov  ah, 0x00     ; BIOS.GetKeyboardKey
    int  0x16         ; -> AX
    cmp  al, 13
    jne  WaitForEnter ; enter_not_pressed
    ret               ; enter_pressed
```

> How I can get the input result and put it into a variable?

That would depend on your use-case.

- If you just want to store the inputted keycodes (AL=ASCII, AH=Scancode) for later inspection, then you could have:

  ```
    mov  ah, 0x00     ; BIOS.GetKeyboardKey
    int  0x16         ; -> AX
    mov  [MyKey], ax

    ...

  MyKey: dw 0
  ```
- If your input is retrieving some text from the user, then the following can be used:

  ```
  GetString:
    mov bx, MyString  ; Get pointer to the allocated space (100 bytes in this case)
  .again:
    mov  ah, 0x00     ; BIOS.GetKeyboardKey
    int  0x16         ; -> AX
    cmp  al, 13
    je   .done
    mov  [bx], al     ; Only storing the character code (ASCII)
    inc  bx           ; Incrementing the pointer by 1, size of an ASCII character
    jmp  .again
  .done:
    mov  byte [bx], 0 ; Make the string zero-terminated
    ret

    ...

  MyString: times 100 db 0
  ```

Comment: How do I block input after submit? I thought the ret command was enough but apparently it doesn't work